# Best way to test out a REST API?

Tags: php, json, api, rest

I just created a REST API using the PHP Slim Framework. However, I would like to know what the best way would be to test out this API would be. Is it best to test it out using PHP or objective-c (where it will be used) or via some online service which allows you to test out a REST API? All outputs are in JSON.

Comment: For what kind of tests are you looking?

Comment: Here are some free [API Testing Tools](https://medium.com/@alicealdaine/top-10-api-testing-tools-rest-soap-services-5395cb03cfa9) you may want to try

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @Martin says, REST implemented properly is independent of the client (assuming it supports your representation types).  So for example you can use the [Poster](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/poster/) add-on for Firefox, or [RestClient 2.3](http://code.google.com/p/rest-client/).

Comment: You can find the chrome port for Poster at https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cdjfedloinmbppobahmonnjigpmlajcd#

Comment: haha, thanks, I'm using Safari though :)

Comment: There's always good ol' curl, which is included in Mac OSX and Linux and has ports to Windows (http://curl.haxx.se/).  If you want to write code to have repeatable tests, you could write it in anything you want (as long as you can make an HTTP request).  The point is, the REST API should be independent of the client.  If it is not independent of the client, test it with Objective-C and optionally argue with someone about whether it is really RESTful or not.

Comment: @Jim Ferrans: I have looked on Poster & RestClient, and it seems they lacks the ability to create TestCase? For example, every time I run a test case I want the same information posted to the server. Do you happen to know any tools already doing that?

Comment: How about wcfstorm.rest?  If you want to send the same information everytime, you can save the request and reload it as often as you want. http://www.wcfstorm.com/wcf/wcfstormrest-lite.aspx

Comment: You can use [behat](http://behat.org/) to do this.

Comment: outdated answer

Answer (score 11):

- You should already have unit tests for this service (e.g. [PHPUnit](/search?q=phpunit)). This ensures everything works as expected.
- You may create acceptance tests (e.g. using [Selenium](/search?q=selenium))
- You may test whether the service is accessible using [CURL](/search?q=curl)

Answer (score 10):

[Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/), an app on the Chrome Webstore is quite good too.

It has a very nice UI. All HTTP methods are supported. It even allows Basic and OAuth autentication and stores your previous requests.

Find the [source code on GitHub here.](https://github.com/a85/POSTMan-Chrome-Extension)

Answer (score 1):

A good REST API should be independent of the end client. So testing it in one scenario, it should be assumed it works in all scenarios using the same endpoints, HTTP verbs, and parameters.

Answer (score 1):

So I useually use a few different tools to test my own / external API's.

[postman](http://www.getpostman.com/) is a HTTP and REST client that runs inside Google Chrome.

[Mocha](http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha/) is a testing framework for Node.js and JavaScript projects. (Link seems to be down atm)

[Nock](https://github.com/pgte/nock) is an HTTP mocking library that can record HTTP calls and play them back, so that you can either mock an API by hand, or just record actual HTTP calls and use their responses in future test runs.

Mocha and Nock are more specific to JavaScript but there is no reason why you couldn't use them for PHP based API's

Comment: > there is no reason why you couldn't use them PHP based APIs.

I'm contemplating using Mocha with Chai to test a REST api built using PhalconPhp. Could there by any potential downsides?

Answer (score 1):

Since RESTful APIs are extremely popular, there are plenty of tools to test them. So the best would be to pick one (or more) of these tools and not waste time and energy on creating large number of own test scripts/procedures.
You can check the following resources that can help you to choose the most suitable tool:

[Top 6 API Testing Tools](http://www.guru99.com/top-6-api-testing-tool.html)
[12 Great Web Service Testing Tools](https://dzone.com/articles/12-great-web-service-testing-tools)

Answer (score 0):

theRightAPI has a free tool that allows you to test any HTTP based API call. You can then save those tests to share with others, or if you need to return later to re-test and ensure the API's continue to respond as expected. It also has a token store that allows you to use singly copies of credentials or authentication keys across multiple tests.

http://www.theRightAPI.com/test

Answer (score 0):

you can use "Advanced REST client" chorem app .

the best of tools i have test.