# Genexus test REST API

Tags: api, openapi, genexus

I am brand new to Genexus and I come over some basic tasks. Now I try to access and test external API-s. I have import API-s over Import OpenAPI process which build API folder and Model folder. I want to test simpe API-s ( list Merchants ) but I cant find the right way to do it. Can somebody help me with that?

TIA

Stane

Comment: Do these links answer your question? -- [What tools do you use to test REST APIs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4486658/113116), [Tools for API testing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30011108/113116), [Best way to test out a REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6809728/113116)

Comment: @Karlek, welcome to the community. please g through this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, it will help you alot

Answer (score 1):

After importing YAML a folder named API is created containing procedures (Genexus objects) that call each service imported.
So, you need to call the procedure that in turn calls the REST service.

Something like:
Merchanlist(Parameters)

Check this document for further information: [https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?31864,OpenAPI%20import%20tool#Sample+consumer+code](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?31864,OpenAPI%20import%20tool#Sample%20consumer%20code)